# Como passar o valor de uma variável para maiúscula ou minuscula?

Tags: bash

Eu tenho um script que recebe uma varável ao executar, por exemplo:

```
./myscript OLA
```

o conteúdo de myscript:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -z $1 ]
then
  echo "Por favor escolha uma opção:"
  echo "OLA - Faz qualquer coisa"
  echo "OLE - Faz outra coisa"
  ...
else
  echo "Vou fazer alguma coisa consoante a variável."
  if [ $1 = "OLA" ]
  then
    echo "Olá amigo."
    ...
```

Eu quero que `./myscript ola` ou `./myscript OlA`, etc também funcionem. Como eu posso passar o `$1` para maiúscula para a comparação? Já agora e para minuscula?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264428/how-to-convert-a-string-to-lower-case-in-bash

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Como havia mencionado nos comentários, existe uma expansão shell para fazer isso: `${variable^^}` vai transformar o texto em `variable` para caixa alta.

Vou copiar os exemplos [desta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2265268/4438007) no StackOverflow internacional, porque ele mostra inclusive comportamentos que eu não conhecia:

```bsh
$ string="a few words"
$ echo "${string^}"
A few words
$ echo "${string^^}"
A FEW WORDS
$ echo "${string^^[aeiou]}"
A fEw wOrds

$ string="A Few Words"
$ declare -u string
$ string=$string; echo "$string"
A FEW WORDS
```

- a expansão com um único circunflexo `${var^}` transforma a *primeira letra* em caixa alta
- a expansão com dois circunflexos `${var^^}` transforma *todas as letras* em caixa alta
- a expansão com uma expressão *blob* após os circunflexos transforma os caracteres que casam com o padrão

Sobre essa expressão com padrão, note que, se você usar com um único circunflexo, ele só colocará em caixa alta se o primeiro caracter bater com a expressão:

```bsh
$ var=abcd
$ echo ${var^[bcd]}
abcd
$ echo ${var^^[bcd]}
aBCD
$ echo ${var^[abcd]}
Abcd
```

Você pode entender a expansão com circunflexo um caso especial da expansão com circunflexo + padrão:

```bsh
$ echo ${var^^?}
ABCD
$ echo ${var^?}
Abcd
```

A vantagem dessa alternativa perante usar `awk`, `tr`, `perl` é que não se inicia um novo processo, a execução toda é feita "diretamente" pelo Bash.

---

Para transformar em minúsculas, a expansão usa vírgulas no lugar do circunflexo. Todo o resto se comporta de maneira análoga:

```bsh
$ string="A FEW WORDS"
$ echo "${string,}"
a FEW WORDS
$ echo "${string,,}"
a few words
$ echo "${string,,[aeiou]}"
a FeW WoRDS

$ string="A Few Words"
$ declare -l string
$ string=$string; echo "$string"
a few words
```

---

Por curiosidade, notou que existe uma declaração especial de variável que a transforma em caixa alta ou caixa baixa na simples atribuição? Isso é feito através do `declare` da variável.

Na resposta de onde peguei os exemplos não encontrei nada que referenciava o porquê do padrão dos argumentos do `declare`, mas achei isso que é extremamente digno de nota:

> The declare options change the attribute of the variable, but not the contents. The reassignments in my examples update the contents to show the changes.

Em tradução livre:

> As opções do `declare` mudam o atributo da variável, mas não seu conteúdo. As reatribuições nos exemplos atualizam o conteúdo para mostrar as mudanças.

Então, por que usar `-u` para caixa alta e `-l` para caixa baixa? Se você pensar no inglês, fica mais fácil lembrar:

- caixa baixa, *lowercase*, `-l`
- caixa alta, *uppercase*, `-u`

Ficam então esses mnemônicos para ajudar na memorização das *flags* da declaração de variáveis.

Answer (score 2):

Pode usar awk para fazer isso. Segue exemplo. Coloque a linha que converte no seu script, antes de fazer o teste. Depois teste com $VAR ao invés de $1

```
   #!/bin/bash
    #$VAR recebe $1 convertido para maiusculas
    VAR=$(echo $1 | awk '{ print toupper($1) }')
    echo "Variavel em maiuscula: $VAR"
```

Comment: Não está errado, porém não é necessário criar um novo processo para fazer isso.

Comment: na verdade, em shell, é quase certeza que vai se criar um novo processo - senão  pra isso, pra quase qualquer coisa - awk talvez seja overkill, mas por outros motivos.

Comment: @jsbueno, há uma expansão de variável que faz isso na Bash, que não faz a criação de um novo processo

Comment: Nas referências que estou encontrando, se usa `awk '{ print toupper($0) }'`, não `$1`. Por exemplo: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14021899/4438007

Comment: Testei com `awk '{ print toupper($0) }'` e com `awk '{ print toupper($1) }'`, obtive os mesmos resultados

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado - não consegue colocar uma resposta aí com sem precisar de outro processo? Seria melhor de qualquer forma.

Comment: @jsbueno, [Já pus](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/424156/64969)